# SQL joining 2 tables without repeating values

Tags: sql, join, duplicates, repeat

I have 2 tables with a 1:n relationship.
I want to join them without repeating (duplicating) the values from the one table.

First, I have a table with budgets:

```
id   name  budget
1    John   1000
2    Kim    3000
```

And second I have a table of spendings:

```
id   amount
1    112
1    145
1    211
```

The result should look like this:

```
id  name   budget amount
1   John   1000   112
1   null   null   145
1   null   null   211
2   Kim    3000   null
```

Output could also be: (this is not important)

```
id  name   budget amount
1   null   null   112
1   John   1000   145
1   null   null   211
2   Kim    3000   null
```

Is this possible with SQL?

Here a join that repeats the values:

```
create temporary table a (id1 int,name varchar(10),budget int);
insert into a (id1,name,budget) values(1,'Maier',1000),(2,'Mueller',2000);
create temporary table if not exists b (id2 int,betrag int);
insert into b (id2,betrag) values(1,100),(1,133),(1,234);
select * from a left join b
on a.id1=b.id2
;
```

Comment: You might find it easier to to this in the client rather than in SQL. Where is the output going?

Comment: Possible? Yes.  Does it make sense in SQL?  Not really, as your results are order dependent, yet have no inherent way of ordering themselves.

Comment: Output is temporary for processing by a program. Doing it in the client is lot more code. It is not order dependent because I don't care wether John is in row 1,2 or 3.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword DISTINCT is used to eliminate duplicate rows from a query result:

```
select distinct b.id, b.name, b.budget, s.amount
from budgets b left join spendings s 
on b.id = s.id;
```

You can also use Group By clause which works similarly like Distinct.In that case,

```
select b.id, b.name, b.budget, s.amount
from budgets b left join spendings s 
on b.id = s.id
group by b.id, b.name, b.budget, s.amount;
```

Comment: He's not trying to eliminate duplicates, he's trying to achieve a presentation style in the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
create  table a (id1 int,name varchar(10),budget int)
insert into a (id1,name,budget) values(1,'Maier',1000)
insert into a (id1,name,budget) values(2,'Mueller',2000)

create  table b (id2 int,betrag int)
insert into b (id2,betrag) values(1,100)
insert into b (id2,betrag) values(1,133)
insert into b (id2,betrag) values(1,234)
insert into b (id2,betrag) values(2,300)
insert into b (id2,betrag) values(2,400)

select a.id1, CASE WHEN c.themin IS NOT NULL THEN a.name ELSE NULL END AS [name],
CASE WHEN c.themin IS NOT NULL THEN a.budget ELSE NULL END AS [budget],
b.*
from a 
LEFT join b on a.id1=b.id2
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT MIN(betrag) AS [themin], id2 FROM b GROUP BY id2) c ON a.id1 = c.id2 AND b.betrag = c.themin
```